# JS not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page, with two buttons: one with `onclick="reShuffle('c')` on it, and the other with `onclick="reShuffle('bw')`. Then, I have this Javascript:

```
function reShuffle(set) {
    if (set = "bw") {
        console.log("Shuffling b&w pictures...");
        var blackAndWhite = shuffle(resize([], 20)); // Second arg is # of images in folder
        go(blackAndWhite, "bw");
    }
    if (set = "c") {
        console.log("Shuffling color pictures...");
        var color = shuffle(resize([],  0)); // Second arg is # of images in folder
        go(color, "c");
    }
    function resize(array, size) {
        for (i = 1; i < size + 1; i++){array.push(i)}
        return array;
    }
    function shuffle(array) {
        var i = array.length,
            j = 0,
            temp;
        while (i--) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        console.log("Array shuffled: " + String(array));
        console.log("Length: " + array.length);
        return array;
    }
    function go(listName, shortname) {
        for (i = 1; i < 16; i++) { // (i = 1; i < # of <img>; i++)
            var index = listName[i - 1];
            console.log( i + ": " + index + " = " + listName[i - 1]);
            document.getElementById("img" + i + shortname).src="imgs/" + shortname + "/" + index + ".jpg";
        }
    }
}

reShuffle("bw");
reShuffle("c");
```

The issue is, that no matter what I do -- `reShuffle("bw")` or `reShuffle("c")`, from button or console, it "reShuffles" both.

What the JS does is it takes 15 random images from a directory and assigns them to 15 `<img>` tags. It does this for both my black and white image section, hence `bw`, and for the color section, hence `c`.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: `if (set = 'bw')` is an assignment, not a comparison; setting the variable is a truthy statement, so the `if` will always be truthy. It's a simple mistake that we've all made, the only solution to it, though, is "be careful." Though there may be further issues with the code that I didn't look for.

Comment: JS is working correctly, JS programmer isn't.

Comment: @Barmar haha, you're right.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oh, my god, how silly of me. Working correctly now, you can create an answer if you like. Kinda surprised JS didn't throw an error, though I guess it *is* imfamous for being bad like that.

Comment: Honestly, while I haven't got the time to search (it's late, I'm meant to be asleep...), I'd be amazed if this isn't a duplicate question/answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas It probably is, in the manner that another one was using `=` instead of `==`, but you can't really have dupe questions for code debugging.

Comment: @DavidThomas Search for what? I said you can create an answer, and I'll accept it, and that I was surprised JS didn't throw an error...

Comment: In which case it's probably 'off-topic' anyway, given it's a typo :)

Comment: @DavidThomas I thought code debugging was OK for SO... Where should I put this type of stuff?

Comment: I never understand why people vote questions like these up (other than to presumably offset the down votes). It's completely off-topic and has a nondescript title. It may not necessarily deserve a down vote, but, in its current state, an up vote is contrary to the ideals of SO.

Comment: @royhowie I agree, these types should never go above 0 points, but, really, SO seems the best SE place for debugging questions... Where else?

Comment: @DavidThomas You gonna create an answer, since you were first, or should I just accept on of the current ones?

Comment: I'm not, no; I am voting to close as off-topic though, given that the error was just a typo. And I'm not sure what use the question offers to others in future, although - as I noted earlier - it's a mistake we've all made at one point or another.

Comment: @DavidThomas I suppose you're in the right. I guess in order to keep my questions as debugging for me, I should narrow them down -- this one could probably have been narrowed down to "JS issues checking input with `if`". That way, I get my debug, and it's still applicable in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter said you need to have

```
if (set == 'bw') {}
```

And

```
if (set == 'c') {}
```

Otherwise an assignment always returns true
and the if test is executed

Comment: Thx. Phone auto correction is a drag on SO

Comment: SO for stack overflow

Comment: Yeah, haha, deleted my comment once I realized that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if statements. You're using single `=`, the assignment operator. So set is becoming "bw", the statement evaluates as true, the code is run. Then the same happens for "c". Use `==` or `===` for comparisons, and it should work just fine.

(If you're a pretty experienced programmer then don't feel at all embarrassed about making a rookie error, I've bashed my head against the wall for hours on end before realising it's something as simple as this. Easy to miss :) )